# Client not able to re-register with eureka server when eureka server restarted

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, heartbeat

The issue always happen on our test environment, but can not reproduce on my local except one time.

The error below here:

> 2018-10-11 10:45:57,198 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] ERROR c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient - Request execution error
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo, and Java type class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo, and MIME media type text/html was not found
>   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:630)
>   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:105)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:824)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1393)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2018-10-11 10:45:57,199 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] WARN c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient - Request execution failed with message: A message body reader for Java class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo, and Java type class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo, and MIME media type text/html was not found
>   2018-10-11 10:45:57,199 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] ERROR c.n.d.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_OSM-ADMIN/10.132.81.36:osm-admin:8082 - was unable to send heartbeat!
>   com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:824)
>   at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1393)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I also saw this answer of https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues/914
but it's not work for me.

On my local, when I stop the eureka server of local, the client will throw "connection refused" ,it's right behavior. the error below here:

> 2018-10-10 17:54:26,693 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] ERROR c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient - Request execution error
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

But when i do it on test environment as same as previous operation, the client throw error like below:

> [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] WARN  c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient - Request execution failed with message: A message body reader for Java class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo, and Java type class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo, and MIME media type text/html was not found
>   2018-10-11 14:30:14,194 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] ERROR c.n.d.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_OSM-ADMIN/10.132.81.36:osm-admin:8082 - was unable to send heartbeat!
>   com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

My spring-boot version is 1.5.10.RELEASE, and org.springframework.cloud  version is 1.4.4.RELEASE

Comment: This issue happened when i use domain ...com for service url. It disappear when i use ip and port directly.

Comment: Not sure whether it's a bug for eureka. Why does work fine for first time register with eureka with domain url, but not work after eureka server restarted.